# External CSS Stylesheet and Images not showing up in Django Web Application when DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django

I have a basic Django Web Application that uses an external CSS style sheet in the `static/css` folder, font-awesome-fonts in the `static/fonts` folder, and user-uploaded images in the `media/images` folder. Whenever I set `DEBUG = False` the image and CSS Style sheets are ignored and just the HTML Template is displayed.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app/
├── myapp/   
├── media/
├── static/
└── templates/
```

```
settings.py

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

I found out how to display media in the main projects `URLs.py` by adding the `if` `else` statements but even when I add the `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to the end of the `urlpatterns[]` it does not display when `DEBUG = False`. I also tried adding `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` as well.

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

# Serving the media files in development mode
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not serve statics when DEBUG=False.

You must add an URL like you did for medias or serve it with another way (frontend or external storage).

Comment: So I tried adding `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to the end of the URL patterns after the media ones and it still did not load. Do I need to do that in the URL Patterns? Or if it was stored locally on the server (I will be hosting this in a Docker Containers) will I just provide the path to it on the server?

Comment: The most basic way is to set a STATIC_ROOT and `manage.py collectstatic`